# Is it possible to estimate particle velocity from a pressure microphone?

Tags: particle-velocity, pressure, microphone

I work with insects which are sensitive to particle velocity (pressure gradient) via their flagellum ears. I need to monitor the sound level of the playback stimuli they are exposed to, however, I only have a pressure microphone and this is not the physical quantity they are sensitive to.

Is there any relationship between particle velocity and pressure?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming a monopole sound source in free-field, RMS particle velocity $v$ and RMS pressure $p$ are related to each other with (chapter 2 p. 51 from [Beranek & Mellow 2012](https://www.sciencedirect.com/book/9780123914217/acoustics-sound-fields-and-transducers))

$$v(r) = \frac{ p(r) }{Z }\sqrt{1 + (\frac{c}{ 2 \pi f r})^2}$$

with $r$ distance to the source,
$Z $ medium impedance,
$ c $ sound speed,
$ f $ sound frequency.

For distance $r$ far greater than the wave length, particle velocity and pressure are proportional:

$$ v(r) = \frac{p(r)}{Z}$$

As a consequence, as long as your speaker is in the far-field of your insect/microphone ($r >> c/f$), you can monitor the particle-velocity level from the pressure level. If not, it is better to have a pressure-gradient microphone (see SE question [How reliable are "particle-velocity" microphones?](https://bioacoustics.stackexchange.com/questions/157/how-reliable-are-particle-velocity-microphones/)).

Answer (score 3):

If you have **two** pressure microphones you can estimate the pressure gradient (and from that, the particle velocity $v$) as

$$v_r(t) \simeq \frac{1}{\rho} \int \frac{p_1(t)-p_2(t)}{\Delta r}dt$$

where $p_1$ and $p_2$ is the sound pressure on the two microphones, $\Delta r $ the spacing of the microphones and $\rho$ the medium density.This measurement estimates only the velocity component oriented along the line connecting the microphones.

Note that the microphones should be phase and amplitude matched.